# Display image from resource file C++ builder : initialization

Tags: c++, c++builder

I want to display alternatively 2 images in the same TImage object from a resource file when clicking on dedicated buttons (so button 1 displays image 1 and button 2 displays image 2).

Here is the very simple code I wrote.
First the header, where I initialized image1 and image2

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef Unit2H
#define Unit2H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ExtCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm2 : public TForm
{
__published:    // Composants gérés par l'EDI
    TImage *Image1;
    TButton *Button1;
    TButton *Button2;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button2Click(TObject *Sender);

private:    
    TResourceStream *image1 = new TResourceStream((int)HInstance, "btn_laser_on", RT_RCDATA);
    TResourceStream *image2 = new TResourceStream((int)HInstance, "btn_up", RT_RCDATA);

public:     
    __fastcall TForm2(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

And the cpp file:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;

__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}

void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Image1->Picture -> LoadFromStream(image1);
}

void __fastcall TForm2::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Image1->Picture -> LoadFromStream(image2);
}
```

This code works (ie Image1 is displayed when Button1 is clicked, and then replaced by Image2 when button2 is clicked) but **only once**.

Clicking again on the button has no action.

Initializing the images directly in the OnClick functions solves the problem. But I want the variables to be accessible anywhere in the class so it is not a valid method.

Since I am rather new at both C++ and C++ Builder, I tried a simpler code where integers instead of images are displayed in a label, just to make sure the initialization in the header file with the `new`method was not causing this. And this works.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Try seeking to the beginning of the stream before reading from it.  Maybe calling `LoadFromStream` leaves it positioned at the end.

Comment: You are right it works like that. I think I did not get quite right the concept of stream. And now I wonder what is the benefit of this instead of just LoadFromFile... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MathieuPaurisse You already know the benefit - loading the picture data from memory instead of from file.  However, in this situation, unless you are loading images frequently, it would be easier to just create and destroy the streams inside the `OnClick` handlers, eg `void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{ TResourceStream *strm = new TResourceStream((int)HInstance, "btn_laser_on", RT_RCDATA); Image1->Picture->LoadFromStream(strm); delete strm; }` rather than creating the streams 1 time at Form creation (which, BTW, you are leaking the streams you are creating).

Comment: @MathieuPaurisse I would actually call the behaviour of `LoadFromStream` a bug.  It should do the seek for you, IMO.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the comment. Indeed I was suspecting a leak from the way I handled this. The solution you pointed was actually the first one I coded. Finally I think that for my application, loading from an image is more appropriate.

Comment: @PaulSanders I would think the same at first sight, but my knowledge and experience with this is too little for my opinion to matter.